# How to click links onto the next page using RCurl?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rcurl

I am trying to scrape this table from [this website](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/clinvar/?term=brca1) using RCurl. I am able to do this and put it into a nice dataframe using the code:

```
clinVar <- getURL("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/clinvar/?term=BRCA1")
docForm2 <- htmlTreeParse(clinVar,useInternalNodes = T) 

xp_expr = "//table[@class= 'jig-ncbigrid docsum_table\']/tbody/tr"
nodes = getNodeSet(docForm2, xp_expr)

extractedData <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes)
colnames(extractedData) <- c("Info","Gene", "Variation","Freq", "Phenotype","Clinical significance","Status", "Chr","Location")
```

However, I can only extract the data on the first page, and the table spans multiple pages. How do you access data on the next page? I have looked at the HTML code for the website and the region that the "Next" button exists in is here (I believe!):

```
<a name="EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.clinVar.clinVar_Entrez_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Pager.Page" title="Next page of results" class="active page_link next" href="#" sid="3" page="3" accesskey="k" id="EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.clinVar.clinVar_Entrez_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Pager.Page">Next &gt;</a>
```

I would like to know how to access this link using `getURL`, `postForm` etc. I think I should be doing something like this, to get data from the second page but it's still just giving me the first page:

```
url <- "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/clinvar/?term=BRCA1"
clinVar <- postForm(url,
                "EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.clinVar.clinVar_Entrez_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Pager.cPage" ="2")
docForm2 <- htmlTreeParse(clinVar,useInternalNodes = T) 

xp_expr = "//table[@class= 'jig-ncbigrid docsum_table\']/tbody/tr"
nodes = getNodeSet(docForm2, xp_expr)

extractedData <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes)
colnames(extractedData) <- c("Info","Gene", "Variation","Freq","Phenotype","Clinical significance","Status", "Chr","Location")
```

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 3):

I would use E-utilities to access data at NCBI instead.

```
url <- "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=clinvar&term=brca1"
readLines(url)
[1] "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
[2] "<!DOCTYPE eSearchResult PUBLIC \"-//NLM//DTD eSearchResult, 11 May 2002//EN\" \"http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/query/DTD/eSearch_020511.dtd\">"                                                                                                                                             
[3] "<eSearchResult><Count>1080</Count><RetMax>20</RetMax><RetStart>0</RetStart><QueryKey>1</QueryKey><WebEnv>NCID_1_36649974_130.14.18.34_9001_1386348760_356908530</WebEnv><IdList>"
```

Pass the QueryKey and WebEnv to esummary and get the XML summary (this changes with each esearch, so copy and paste the new keys into the url below)

```
url2 <-  "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=clinvar&query_key=1&WebEnv=NCID_1_36649974_130.14.18.34_9001_1386348760_356908530"
brca1 <- xmlParse(url2)
```

Next, view a single record and then extract the fields you need.  You may need to loop through the set if there are 0 to many values assigned to a tag.  Others like clinical significance description always have 1 value.

```
getNodeSet(brca1, "//DocumentSummary")[[1]]
table(xpathSApply(brca1, "//clinical_significance/description", xmlValue) )

                      Benign conflicting data from submitters                     not provided                            other 
                         129                               22                                6                                1 
                  Pathogenic          probably not pathogenic              probably pathogenic                      risk factor 
                         508                               68                               19                               43 
      Uncertain significance 
                         284
```

Also, there are many packages with E-utilities on github and BioC (rentrez, reutils, genomes and others). Using the genomes package on BioC, this simplifies to

```
brca1 <- esummary( esearch("brca1", db="clinvar"), parse=FALSE )
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks so much for your reply. I had looked at the eUtilities api and hit a brick wall, but your getNodeSet() usage helped me completely. This is solved, I'll post my answer to this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Using the e-utilities feature on the NCBI database, see http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25500/ for more details.

```
## use eSearch feature in eUtilities to search NCBI for ids corresponding to each row of data.
## note to see all ids, not not just top 10 set retmax to a high number
## to get query id and web env info, set usehistory=y

library(RCurl)
library(XML)

baseSearch <- ("http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=") ## eSearch
db <- "clinvar" ## database to query
gene <- "BRCA1" ## gene of interest
query <-  paste('[gene]+AND+"','clinsig pathogenic"','[Properties]+AND+"','single nucleotide     variant"','[Type of variation]&usehistory=y&retmax=1110',sep="") ## query, see below for details
baseFetch <- "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=" ## base fetch

searchURL <- paste(baseSearch,db, "&term=",gene,query,sep="")
getSearch <- getURL(searchURL)
searchHTML <- htmlTreeParse(searchURL, useInternalNodes =T)
nodes <- getNodeSet(searchHTML,"//querykey") ## this name "querykey" was extracted from the HTML source code for this page
querykey <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes)
nodes <- getNodeSet(searchHTML,"//webenv") ## this name "webenv" was extracted from the HTML source code for this page
webenv <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes)
fetchURL <-     paste(baseFetch,db,"&query_key=",querykey,"&WebEnv=",webenv[[1]],"&rettype=docsum",sep="")
getFetch <- getURL(fetchURL)
fetchHTML <- htmlTreeParse(getFetch, useInternalNodes =T)
nodes <- getNodeSet(fetchHTML, "//position")
extractedDataAll <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes)
colnames(extractedDataAll) <- c("pathogenicSNPs")
print(extractedDataAll)
```

Please note, I found the query information by going to http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/clinvar/?term=BRCA1 selecting my filters (pathogenic, etc) and then clicking the advanced button. The most recent filters applied should come up in the main box, I used this for the query.

Answer (score 0):

ClinVar now offers XML download of the whole database so webscraping is not necessary.